# HTTP 403 when sending metrics to CloudWatch in Frankfurt, works in Ireland

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

We use `mon-get-instance-stats.pl` to send custom metrics (RAM and Disk usage) to Cloudwatch.

I set this up [following the AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/mon-scripts.html). We use instance roles to give the instances the right to call CloudWatch, we do not use access keys.

This works like a charm for our Ireland (eu-west-1) instances but fails for our Frankfurt (eu-central-1) instances, where I get this error message:

```
$ /home/ec2-user/aws-scripts-mon/mon-put-instance-data.pl --mem-util --mem-used --mem-avail --swap-util --swap-used --disk-path=/ --disk-space-util --disk-space-used --disk-space-avail --aws-iam-role=instancerole 

ERROR: Failed to call CloudWatch: HTTP 403. Message: The security token included in the request is invalid

For more information, run 'mon-put-instance-data.pl --help'
```

Note that the role `instancerole` is correctly configured on EC2 instances on both Ireland and Frankfurst.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, because Frankfurt is a new region, is does not support the old version of Cloudwatch scripts. I was running version 1.1.0, updating to 1.2.1 fixed the issue.